# Nearby cycles for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, nearby-cycles

Let $X$ be a variety over $\mathbb C$. Let $f\colon X \to \mathbb{A}^1$ be a regular function. I understand that there is an analytic nearby cycles functor, defined in terms of the exponential map. I also understand that there is an algebraic nearby cycles, defined in SGA 7.

Questions:

1. What is the relationship between these two functors?
2. Is there a good theory in the case where X is either infinite dimensional, or X is a stack, or both?

Any references would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the analytic nearby cycle functor? The algebraic nearby cycle is defined on the category of (algebraic) étale sheaves, but what about the analytic one?

Comment: @Z. M The analytic definition has been defined by Beilinson Berstein and Deligne I think and you can see it here : https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3259. §2.3.
I don't know the algebraic version though, what is it ?

Comment: @NikolaTomić The algebraic one that I am vaguely aware of is only looking at the unipotent part. Roughly speaking, for every positive integer $n$, you pull the map $f$ back along Kummer coverings $(-)^n\colon\mathbb A^1\to\mathbb A^1$, obtaining $g_n\colon Y\to\mathbb A^1$, and you look at the $C_n$-equivariant étale sheaves on the recollement determined by the closed subscheme $g_n^{-1}(0)\subseteq Y$. This is the usual way to approximate the exponential map in the algebraic setting.

Comment: Yes, the analytic one I am aware of is defined in terms of the exponential covering map (please correct me if I am wrong) for $\mathbb{C}^*$. And for the algebraic one, which I know almost nothing about, it is defined in SGA by Grothendieck and there are some notes by Illusie here: https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~luc.illusie/vanishing1b.pdf

Comment: @Z.M In what sense is the algebraic one looking only at the unipotent part? Pulling back along the $n$th Kummer covering will detect local monodromy with eigenvalues of order n.

Comment: @WillSawin I am not working within this field thus maybe I misunderstood something, but here it is: if you construct the nearby cycle functor via Kummer coverings on étale motives (maybe denoted by $\operatorname{DM}^{\operatorname{ét}}$ in the literature, and recall that $\ell$-adically it is the same as $\ell$-adic coefficients), and then you specialize to the Betti world, you only see the (pro-)unipotent part. I might confuse something, since I remember that the base in question was a DVR, so maybe this only happens in the mixed characteristic case?

Comment: @Z.M It seems that the OP asked to compare two different kinds of nearby cycles but there exist so many different kinds and each commenter is familiar with a different subset of them that we might never figure out what each other are talking about, let alone answer the question. I'm not familiar with etale motives, but the nearby cycles functor defined for $\ell$-adic etale sheaves certainly sees more than just unipotent monodromy.

Comment: The monodromy you get depends on what coverings you use: If you use Kummer morphisms you will only see tame monodromy, which is more general than unipotent, but in the mixed or equal characteristic $p$ case is less than everything. But if we're comparing with analysis we're in characteristic zero so that's irrelevant.

Comment: To add Will Sawin, there are several choices of a theory of nearby cycles, based on the kind of covering, at least in étale cohomology, you get the unipotent one and the tame one and they coincide if the scheme is of semi-stable form, i.e. $S[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1...x_k - \pi) \to S$ with $\pi$ a uniformizer. In general, the tame contains the unipotent as a direct summand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a reference, but let me discuss a strategy for a proof of the comparison that I think should work.

By Artin's comparison, if we take a constant sheaf $\mathbb Z/\ell^n$ and then pull back to the cover where we invert $f$ and adjoin an $m$th root of $f$, pushforward to $X$, and then pull back to the zero locus of $f$, the resulting complex of sheaves will not depend on if we perform these operations in the worlds of analytic or étale sheaves.

We want to use this as a building block for the comparison. The way to do this to observe there is a natural map from the above complex for $m_1$ to the above complex for $m_2$ if $m_1$ divides $m_2$, and so we can take a colimit as $m$ goes to $\infty$. After this, we can take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$. This gives nearby cycles as a $\mathbb Z_\ell$-sheaf, and then we can tensor with $\mathbb Q_\ell$. If we do this in the étale world, we recover the usual construction of nearby cycles.

Indeed, the only difference between what I said and the usual construction is that the usual construction involves pulling back to the algebraic closure of some local field, i.e. (in characteristic zero) to the inverse limit of all these coverings (together with étale neighborhoods of zero in $\mathbb A^1$, which are irrelevant after taking $i^*$). But the pushforward from the inverse limit of coverings is the colimit of the pushforward from coverings by [a general result](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09YQ) (applied one open set at a time, since it's stated in terms of global sections rather than sheaves) with hypotheses that are easily checked in this case.

So it suffices to check that this construction agrees with the usual construction in the analytic world, where we adjoin a logarithm of $f$ instead of an $m$'th root, and where we work with $\mathbb Q$ coefficients. I would attempt this in two steps:

First, like in the étale world, check that the cohomology of the colimits of the finite covers agrees with the cohomology of the infinite cover. I would do this by expressing the finite cover as the quotient of the infinite cover by $\log f \mapsto \log f + 2\pi i m$ so the cohomology of the finite cover can be computed from the cohomology of the infinite cover and the action of the operator $\log f \mapsto \log f + 2 \pi i m$, i.e. the $m$th power of a generator of monodromy. Thinking about the action of this operator should give the statement.

Next, check that the $\mathbb Q_\ell$-cohomology constructed this way isjust the usual $\mathbb Q$-cohomology tensored with $\mathbb Q$. This should just require using the universal coefficient theorem to calculate the $\mathbb Z/\ell^n$ cohomology in terms of the $\mathbb Z$ cohomology and use that the $\mathbb Z$-cohomology is a finitely generated abelian group (surely that is known in this setting even with the logarithm map) to see that the inverse limit over $n$ agrees with the tensor product with $\mathbb Z_\ell$, then tensor both sides with $\mathbb Q$.

Everything I say should work with stacks but now finding references to individual steps will be more difficult.

In the infinite-dimensional case, it depends what you mean, but the étale side would usually be a limit of finite-dimensional things so the question is if the analytic side is as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the relation between the algebraic nearby cycles functors (at this point, I believe that the algebraic in your mind is the one in étale cohomology, which is somehow analogous but irrelevant here as the setting is $X \longrightarrow S$ with $S$ a strict local trait) and their analytic counterparts are compatible but there is such a compatibility in the motivic world. Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-variety and $X^{an}$ the complex points $X(\mathbb{C})$ endowed with the analytic topology. We denote by $\mathbf{SH}(X)$ the motivic stable homotopy category of Morel-Voevodsky and $\mathbf{D}(X^{an})$ the derived category of sheaves of abelian groups. Then Ayoub constructed a Betti realization
$$\operatorname{Betti}_X \colon \mathbf{SH}(X) \longrightarrow \mathbf{D}(X^{an})$$
which is compatible with four operations $(f^*,f_*,f_!,f^!)$ and moreover, compatible with appropriate nearby cycles functors. More precisely, given a morphism $f \colon X \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$, and let
$$\Psi_{f} \colon \mathbf{SH}(X_{\eta}) \longrightarrow \mathbf{SH}(X_{\sigma})$$
$$\Psi_{f^{an}} \colon \mathbf{D}(X_{\eta}^{an}) \longrightarrow \mathbf{D}(X_{\sigma}^{an})$$ be the motivic nearby cycles functor (constructed in Ayoub's thesis, it is more or less the same thing as you commented, and it is the tame one, not the unipotent) and the analytic nearby cycles functors (if I remember correctly, this one is in SGA7), Ayoub proved that there is an isomorphism
$$\operatorname{Betti}_{X_{\eta}} \circ \Psi_f(A) \simeq \Psi_{f^{an}} \circ \operatorname{Betti}_{X_{\sigma}}(A)$$ when $A$ is a constructible motive. I do not know if we can replace $\mathbf{SH}$ with some other motivic theory, but in general, all reasonable theory of nearby cycles should be a non-virtual version of a virtual one coming from Grothendieck rings of varieties. More concrete, if we let $\mathscr{M}_X = K_0(\mathrm{Var}_X)[(\mathbb{A}_X^1)^{-1}]$ to be the Grothendieck ring of $X$-varieties, then Guibert-Loeser-Merle built a nearby cycles morphism
$$\psi_f \colon \mathscr{M}_{X_{\eta}} \longrightarrow \mathscr{M}_{X_{\sigma}}$$
and there are commutative diagrams
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathscr{M}_{X_{\eta}} @>{\psi_f}>> \mathscr{M}_{X_{\sigma}} \\
@V{\chi_{X_{\eta},c}}VV @VV{\chi_{X_{\sigma},c}}V\\
K_0(H(X_{\eta})) @>{\Psi_f}>> K_0(H(X_{\sigma}))
\end{CD}
where $\chi$ denotes the Euler characteristic with compact support, and with $H$ being $MHM$ (mixed Hodge modules, by Guibert-Loeser-Merle), being $D^b_c$ (derived category of sheaves, by Denef-Loeser), being $\mathbf{SH}$ (by Ivorra-Sebag),...

The reason that all these theories look alike is that they all satisfy the so-called semi-stable reduction (in 'etale cohomology, it is the work of Rapoport-Zink), which roughly speaking, allows you to compute the nearby cycles functor when the special fiber is of semi-stable form (looks like a monomial, or a resolution of singularities if you prefer this terminology).

To answer your question, at least with $\mathbf{SH}(X)$, we do not require $X$ to be finitely dimensional, just quasi-compact and quasi-separated is already enough.

For stacks, I am aware of the work of Cisinski and Pippi, *Étale tame vanishing cycles over* $[\mathbb{A}^1_S/\mathbb{G}_{m,S}]$ but not read the details yet.

Comment: The algebraic one is not irrelevant at all. One can just pull back from $\mathbb A^1$ to the spectrum of the étale local ring of $\mathbb A^1$ at a point which is a strict local trait.